# iOS IAP, how to judge multiple user at the same device

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

**For example**: There are two different game characters in a single iPhone device,
we call it A and B.

First, app user login as A, he perform an IAP action, the A logout without the purchase completed.

Then, app user login as B, then purchase finish event arrival, this is the problem, how to judge the receipt belongs to A, not B.

I googled, found `SKMutablePayment.requestData` may be used for solve this problem, but **Apple Document** told me this is a reserved property, and must be nil, or else then payment will be reject.

> requestData
>   Reserved for future use. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSData *requestData Discussion
>   The default value is nil. If requestData is not nil, your payment
>   request will be rejected.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 3.0 and later. Declared In **SKPayment.h**

Comment: so your question is, how to pass the user identity (such as user name) along with the IAP request?

Comment: @Raptor yes, I think.

Comment: I think this is a non-problem. Signing out does not remove your IAPs.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman, Yes, the IAP still exist, but I don't know it belong to A or B?

Comment: IAPs are anonymous anyway, you can't tell the difference between A & B. You can only get valid receipts or not.

Comment: Presumably you are referring to consumable IAP, not non-consumable.  If it is non-consumable you would just unlock for all 'users'.  How are users 'logging in' - Are you referring to the game centre login or some login within your application?  Either way you need to keep a record of the transaction-in progress within the app.  When the purchase completes you only need to look at the outstanding purchases in your data store.  Purchases will complete quite quickly so it is unlikely that another purchase would be queued before the first one had completed

Comment: @RhythmicFistman , thanks, may be I should change my business logic to fix this problem. I just want to find some thing like "Android IAB, developerPayload property" in iOS. but it seems not exist.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, I use the type of "consumable", I use private account system, the user can register, login, switch as different character,
if the purchase finish quickly, there is no problem. I just want to make things right with any condition.

Comment: @Paulw11, keep a transaction and username associate record may help me to resolve this problem, but it not absolutely correct.

Answer (score 7):

thanks for everyone's reply

finally, I found SKMutablePayment.applicationUsername can save my private account username,
but It only available on iOS7.0.

save:

```
SKMutablePayment* payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct:product];
payment.applicationUsername = @"my_username_1001";
```

read:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{            
     for (SKPaymentTransaction* trans in transactions) {
        switch (trans.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:trans];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                // got private user account here
                NSString* applicationUsername = [[trans payment] applicationUsername];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great find any idea how to handle this on ios6?

Comment: This is very good approach :) but i am facing a problem when i try to restore transactions. After restoring, applicationUsername returns NULL. Can you help me?

Comment: @AlexSamnas did you try trans.originalTransaction.applicationUsername?

Comment: @LolaRun No, i finally found another way for Restoring Transactions problem. Here is how i fixed it (and it works great): http://stackoverflow.com/a/25768965/3233154

Comment: @LolaRun: is  trans.originalTransaction.applicationUsername actually works? have you tested it?

I dont want to try Alex   Samnas approach coz it may take me another set on attribute on my table lol.

Comment: According to a post elsewhere by an Apple employee, applicationUserName should be set to allow Apple to detect strange things (aka fraud) going on on the app store. The applicationUserName will stay in the SKPayment object that you created and where you set it, but will not be filled in by Apple for SKPayment objects coming from the store (restoring for example).

Comment: @gnasher729 can you please provide the link to that post?

Comment: @user129823:  Yes its working great with iOS 7 and later iOS version but when i tried same things for OS X 10.11 then its returning null all time after close app and reopen again.
Any suggestion?