# SKMutablePayment property: applicationUsername

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am implementing In App Purchases in my app and I am using Non-Consumable Products. 
I have User Login in my application and to prevent Irregular Activity apple sugests to use ***applicationUsername*** property, so I can send along with the payment the user's username.

Everything works fine, i can set *payment.applicationUsername* property and I can retrieve it back after the purchase is finished in *SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased* state.

The problem is that, when i try to ***Restore*** my transactions with the *restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername*: method the applicationUsername property returns NULL.

Can you help me please?

Comment: I am facing the same issue on SandBox mode. Is there anyone can get applicationUsername from transaction in state "Restored" ?

Comment: @fuatcoskun See my answer please, and happy coding :) (It works perfect as i have implemented this by myself)

Comment: Have you tested the scenario where a user changes apple id on the device and tries to purchase the same subscription period again (by mistake or maybe intentionally to avail a second trial period maybe). I wanted to know how does Apple respond to the same if it detects the same application user with different Apple Ids?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a lot of research i found that we can't use *applicationUsername* for this purpose.

For a restoreCompletedTransaction you can use the  ***transaction.originalTransaction.transactionIdentifier*** property 
(and it's equivalent under a new purchase - transaction.transactionIdentifier).

That is a *unique identifier* associated with the Purchase itself and iTunes Account that is found in the restore record.

**1. How to use it:**

> Record that Original transactionIdentifier on your server as
>   associated with the original purchase by user A.

***2. Detect Irregular Activity***

> If another user tries to restore their purchase check to be sure the
>   transactionIdentifier has not already been used under a different
>   userName.

If this transactionIdentifier has not been been used from none of your users than make your restore successful. If the transactionIdentifier has already been used from another user than explain the user why you can't make the restore.

> This is essentially equivalent to using
>   'transaction.transactionIdentifier' as the 'applicationUsername'.

Comment: Hi Alex just wanted to know more about the issue as I am going to handle in-app purchase with user accounts too. By "the applicationUsername property returns NULL" do you mean the applicationUsername in `SKPayment` returned in `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` ? And what do you mean by "we can't use applicationUsername for this purpose" ? Do you mean restoring purchased contents based on applicationUsername or use it to check if this specific user purchased the content locally? Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate on `After a lot of research i found that we can't use applicationUsername for this purpose.`

Comment: Hi Alex,When I try to store on server but at time network(Internet) is gone and server storing fail. after some time network(internet) comes. Any other user try to restore. But we can not different user because of we don't have 'transaction.transactionIdentifier' on server. can you please share your though?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use applicationUsername property at our end, we already have the userId. It must be apple doing something detecting the irregular activity. However, I have found no trace of what they do post detecting a irregular activity.