# Apple In-App Purchase : How to detect the owner of the payment in an multi-user app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My app is an multi-user app , similar to WeChat or QQ . When `User1` start a payment :

```
SKMutablePayment *payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct:product];
payment.quantity = 1;
payment.applicationUsername = [self hashedValueForAccountName:accountName];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addPayment:payment];
```

Here , I cannot find some property to provide an user-defined data such as user account number , the applicationUsername is only used to detect irregular activity for Apple's server and can not be inserted into the `receipt` when the transaction is finished .

`User1` will got notification when the transaction is finished .

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue )queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray )transactions{
    //...
}
```

But if the transaction can not be notified by Apple because some network reason or any other reason , and I **close my app ** then restart app and login with `User2` . Apple will notify my app with last transaction.

Because the transaction (receipt) does not contains 'User Identifier', I can not judge the transaction's ownership.

---

I have read almost all the documents of In-App Purchase provided by Apple, such as https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/ and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html , but I can not find any answers .

How could I do ? Thanks .

Comment: Go through the below answer, might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480869/skmutablepayment-property-applicationusername/25768965#25768965

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps .

Comment: Would love it if you can upvote or aceept my answer. :)

Comment: Hi Vikas,When I try to store on server but at time network(Internet) is gone and server storing fail. after some time network(internet) comes. Any other user try to restore. But we can not different user because of we don't have 'transaction.transactionIdentifier' on server. So What we do? can you please share your though?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work, but `applicationUsername` property on the SKPayment object can be retrieved in the payment callback. All you have to do is set the property while making the payment.

[SKMutablePayment property: applicationUsername](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480869/skmutablepayment-property-applicationusername)

The question in the above link states that it is retrieved in the payments object. I have not tested that for myself.

As for Restores, you should link the `transaction.transactionId` of your purchase to your application user and use `transaction.original.transactionIdentifier` while making a restore purchase.

Now the tricky part here is whether multiple accounts in your app can all make the same purchase individually (purchase within a subscription group in case of subscriptions). How can multiple accounts make the same purchase being tied to the same Apple Id. I am not sure if that's even possible. Because the purchase happens for one App Store account and not the application account.